# Server unexpectedly closed

Tags: ssh, firewall

So I know that similar veins to this topic have been posted, but mine specifically deals with the fact that my SSH login through Putty worked from my desktop and my laptop.

However, after carrying out some steps to secure it, my laptop can still gain access through SSH but my desktop kicks me out and says:

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection

The fact that I can still connect from one and not the other means that the port is fine, but what firewall feature is causing this issue? I am using 12.04. I have uninstalled Fail2Ban and DenyHosts as a test, and this didn't fix the problem. The port is open, I have checked.

Comment: You can add `-v` key to see debugging messages. `ssh -v you@youserver`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove known_host from desktop
Putty stores known hosts under a registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SoftWare\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys

After removing try to connect

Comment: now none of my putty sessions are working... I reinstalled ubuntu and have it listening on a specific port, have openssh installed and putty still will not work. Any suggestions would be welcome as I have spent hours on this already!

Comment: the problem went away for some reason. I reinstalled the entire OS  and reconfigured the ports and it seems to work. Thanks!